# Laravel Angular CORS issue in Authentication

Tags: angularjs, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, cors

I am following this tutorial to set up authentication with tokens using Laravel and Angular.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

This works fine but when I host Laravel (as backend) separately, and Angular frontend on another domain, I get the foolowing error in console :-

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jotdot.mysite.com/api/authenticate.
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but 
only one is allowed. Origin 'http://jotdotfrontend.mysite.com' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

I've placed a CORS middleware in Laravel and it works fine for simple routes.

```
class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')-  >header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}

}
```

How do I add CORS middleware to this :-

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' =>    ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
```

Adding it next to ['prefix' => 'api'] did not solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update the routes example to show how you added the middleware to the route group definition?

Comment: @watcher - I updated it, there was another way I did it, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that your middleware is most likely acting like an 'after' middleware, and as such isn't modifying the request before it's returned to the client. Instead it is modifying the request *after* it is sent, which doesn't do you any good.

Try modifying your `handle` function like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $request->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    $request->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: getting an error - Call to a member function header() on string. checking for it

Comment: yes this resolved the header issue, but still console giving the error - "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: At least that's a different error, so, progress! See the update. I added the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header, but you may not need to include all of the ones I did (or you may need to include more than I did).  According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers), you only need to include that header on the preflight (OPTIONS) request

Comment: I added "$request->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);" but still same error.

Comment: @StacyJ that's because that's not what the current error is complaining about. Add the _`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`_ header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94216/discussion-between-stacy-j-and-watcher).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 methods to solve this issue so far.
I have explained the solution in my answer for another question on this site.

Please check the following answer:

[Angular CORS Issue for Laravel Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306481/cors-issue-for-angular-laravel-project/41306660#41306660)