# CORS issue for Angular + Laravel project

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

I am having trouble to create web app using Angular which is accessing to RESTful API built by Laravel.
Although I have created middleware which passes correct headers, it does not work.

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
    }
}
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest cannot load [link](http://example.com). Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. This error occurred when I was accessing with post method to the api server.

Comment: @ArviPalmu You should specify more details what issues you see so far. You d better show some HTTP request headers which ends up on failure, so that others will have good understanding on what you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is a kind of annoying issue, I know, but there are 2 solutions.

## 1.

You define OPTIONS method for every API calling route, and make it pass the middleware you created like following:

```
Route::options('todos/{any?}', ['middleware' => 'cors', function(){return;}]);
Route::options('projects/{any?}', ['middleware' => 'cors', function(){return;}]);
```

## 2

You hack Laravel core class file, so that it passes CORS header for every OPTIONS request.

in the

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/framework/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
```

you will find following function

```
protected function getRouteForMethods($request, array $methods)
    {
        if ($request->method() == 'OPTIONS') {
            return (new Route('OPTIONS', $request->path(), function () use ($methods) {
                return new Response('', 200, ['Allow' => implode(',', $methods)]);
            }))->bind($request);
        }

        $this->methodNotAllowed($methods);
    }
```

Update this function to following, so that it will pass CORS headers for OPTIONS request

```
protected function getRouteForMethods($request, array $methods)
    {
        if ($request->method() == 'OPTIONS') {
            return (new Route('OPTIONS', $request->path(), function () use ($methods) {
                return new Response('', 200, [
                    'Allow' => implode(',', $methods),
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
                ]);

            }))->bind($request);
        }

        $this->methodNotAllowed($methods);
    }
```

So for me, both solutions work okay. Choice is yours.
But solution #2 is something hack on Laravel core, you might have some issues if you upgrade Laravel itself? But at least it has less coding. :D

Hope these solutions will be helpful.

Comment: @RayC This is a great solution!!! I have adopted solution #2, and it worked as charming!!! I have searched to solve the issue all over the google, but failed, no luck, and though I was trapped. THANKS very much!

Comment: #2: you shouldn't modify the vendor files in any case