# Laravel + Angular accessing from outside network blocked by CORS

Tags: angular, laravel, server, cors

All questions i have seen on this topic have been on a local network, but i haven't seen any that answer it for an outside the network connection.

I have a laravel backend and a Angular (and ionic) frontend. If i host them on 192.168.x.x:XXXX and i access them from within my network everything is fine, and they do all HTTP requests perfectly and there are no CORS errors.

The problem comes when i try to access use the applications from outside the network. I have setup the port forwarding needed to access the application from the outside, so if i access from any browser outside the network to x.x.x.x(my public IP):XXXX(port which its running on) i have access to the application, both the backend and the frontend.

But if i try any action within the application, for example a login,(keep in mind i changed the request IP to the appropriate public IP in these methods ) i get a CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://(My public IP)/_connect_hashaudit_/frame/public/test?hash=6918596600873537056&id=34686533401. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

These are my CORS settings in my laravel app:

```
'paths' => ['*'], //Set to all to avoid CORS errors when accessing the server during development

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => ['*'],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

I am running them on XAMPP Apache

I understand how these servers are intended for development use only, but i would like if i could demonstrate these apps remotely. I'm not going to leave these servers running. Is there any way to solve this, or run these servers on something else to get around this?

Comment: [Refer to this, seems similar kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41306660/10268779)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed. The message *“CORS request did not succeed”* actually indicates the cause of the problem was not a CORS issue, but instead some more serious failure — and the CORS error is just a side effect of that other problem. So you need to do some further troubleshooting to figure out what the actual problem is. But the problem is not with the CORS settings in your Laravel app. Instead there”s some network problem or something.

Answer (score 0):

As @sideshowbaker mentioned the CORS error was just a symptom of another error. It turns out that XAMPP doesn't allow you to do this unless you run it in administrator mode